# screenShot code Not working on ipad, works on iphone

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, glreadpixels

i am having this strange problem...
i had to capture the screen data and convert it into an image using the following code..this code is working fine over iphone/ipad simulator and on iphone device but not on iPad only .
iphone device is having ios version 3.1.1 and ipad is ios 4.2...

```
- (UIImage *)screenshotImage {
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
int backingWidth = screenBounds.size.width;
int backingHeight =screenBounds.size.height;
NSInteger myDataLength = backingWidth * backingHeight * 4;
GLuint *buffer = (GLuint *) malloc(myDataLength);
glReadPixels(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight, GL_RGBA4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
for(int y = 0; y < backingHeight / 2; y++) {
    for(int xt = 0; xt < backingWidth; xt++) {
        GLuint top = buffer[y * backingWidth + xt];
        GLuint bottom = buffer[(backingHeight - 1 - y) * backingWidth + xt];
        buffer[(backingHeight - 1 - y) * backingWidth + xt] = top;
        buffer[y * backingWidth + xt] = bottom;
    }
}
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, myDataLength, releaseScreenshotData);
const int bitsPerComponent = 8;
const int bitsPerPixel = 4 * bitsPerComponent;
const int bytesPerRow = 4 * backingWidth;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(backingWidth,backingHeight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

// myImage = [self addIconToImage:myImage];
return myImage;}
```

Any idea whats going wrong ..??

Answer (score 2):

Those two lines don't match

```
NSInteger myDataLength = backingWidth * backingHeight * 4;

glReadPixels(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight, GL_RGBA4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

`GL_RGB4` means *4 bits per channel*, however you're allocating for 8 bits per channel. The proper token is `GL_RGB8`. On the iPhone `GL_RGB4` may be unsupported and falls back to `GL_RGBA`.

Also make sure you're reading from the correct buffer (front vs. left vs. any (accidently) bound FBOs). I recommend reading from the back buffer before doing the buffer swap.

Comment: k thanks for quick reply.. now i had changed GL_RGB4 to GL_RGBA. code is running good on iphone device but not on ipad device any idea whats the problem....i m using same code for both devices

Comment: Change it to GL_RGBA8, not just GL_RGBA (note the '8').

Comment: hey my xcode is not giving me the option of GL_RGBA8 exactly instead it giving GL_RGBA8_OES as option ..when i use this GL_RGBA8_OES it gives compile time error that ""GL_RGBA8_OES is not defined in this scope ""

Comment: @Tornado: OES headers are included?

Comment: Hmmmm.. Opengl framework is included in project ... i had included      #import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>  ..... what else i had to import ?

Comment: k now all OES headers included... tried GL_RGBA8_OES does not work on ipad device......hey strange thing is in simulator it works whether i change it to any option GL_RGBA4,Gl_RGB, and all..

Answer (score 0):

for ios 4 or later i m using Multi-Sampling technique for anti-aliasing ....glReadpixels() cannot read directly from multiSampled FBO you need to resolve it to Single sampled buffer and then try reading it...Please refer to the following post :-

[Reading data using glReadPixel() with multisampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869577/problem-in-reading-data-using-glreadpixel)

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot from openGL ES apple documentation

```
- (UIImage*)snapshot:(UIView*)eaglview
{
    GLint backingWidth, backingHeight;

    // Bind the color renderbuffer used to render the OpenGL ES view
    // If your application only creates a single color renderbuffer which is already bound at this point, 
    // this call is redundant, but it is needed if you're dealing with multiple renderbuffers.
    // Note, replace "_colorRenderbuffer" with the actual name of the renderbuffer object defined in your class.
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, _colorRenderbuffer);

    // Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth, height = backingHeight;
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

    // Read pixel data from the framebuffer
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    // Create a CGImage with the pixel data
    // If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
    // otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                    ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // OpenGL ES measures data in PIXELS
    // Create a graphics context with the target size measured in POINTS
    NSInteger widthInPoints, heightInPoints;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) {
        // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
        // Set the scale parameter to your OpenGL ES view's contentScaleFactor
        // so that you get a high-resolution snapshot when its value is greater than 1.0
        CGFloat scale = eaglview.contentScaleFactor;
        widthInPoints = width / scale;
        heightInPoints = height / scale;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints), NO, scale);
    }
    else {
        // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
        widthInPoints = width;
        heightInPoints = height;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints));
    }

    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // UIKit coordinate system is upside down to GL/Quartz coordinate system
    // Flip the CGImage by rendering it to the flipped bitmap context
    // The size of the destination area is measured in POINTS
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthInPoints, heightInPoints), iref);

    // Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Clean up
    free(data);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);

    return image;
}
```